# Can Caching cause my WAF logged events to drop?

Tags: wordpress, waf, cache

I've been using Ninjafirewall on WordPress websites for a while.

I recently installed a new caching plugin on my main website and I noticed the firewall log which usually has around 5000 blocked threats per month has less than 10 so far this month when I would expect to be over 1000 so far.

Everything appears to be running fine... except barely any logs

Can a new caching plugin cause this? It kinda makes sense that cached pages aren't triggering events like a normal page would.

Should I be looking anywhere else specifically? How worried should I be at this point?

Comment: turns out that after a major update the htaccess file was pointing the firewall to the old directory and the logs were there. big duh moment

Answer (score 1):

Web application firewalls are designed to process the http request on webserver before is it processed by the web server. It passes through Ninjafirewall for any malicious layer 7 protocol payload i.e. command injection, XSS, Cross Site Request Forgery etc.

Cache is a temporary memory space where already processed requests are pushed with out processing by server.

Therefore, a plugin-based firewall of WordPress will not get through this requests.

However, an actual WAF placed at network layer will process it i.e. if WAF of Fortinet, Barcauda which is placed at perimeter layer will act differently as all http request will go through this perimeter firewall before reaching the webserver cache.

Comment: I wasn't positive which would happen first. I'm still unsure about the cause. Either my website is receiving 99% less sketchy traffic then usual or something isn't working correctly